# Firefox turns on touch pad and screen

Tags: touchpad

I received 5 answers to my original question, 'How do I disable touch pad when using a mouse'. I tried the first suggestion and it worked after many hours or days,I don't remember. I became disgusted and went back to Windows 10. Then after a period I rebooted Ubuntu and decided to play a card game and the touch pad nor the touch pad were active to my delight!! I tried a write document and same thing.
Then I opened Firefox did a search or something and the cursor wasn't where it  supposed to be. I ran my finger across the display and the cursor followed it, also ran my finger over the touch pad and it did the same thing. I shut down the computer, restarted with mouse active and also the problem.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What make and model of touch pad? Since Ubuntu was off for a while, an undisclosed period of time, did you run update and upgrade to make sure the system was up to date?

Comment: since I left the comment/question I found the answer. My appologies for the delay. Simply open the settings (click the down arrow in the uppermost right corner of the screen) and choose 'settings'. Click on 'Mouse & Touchpad" I totally overlooked the slide to turn the touchpad off. It simply came as the default in the on position. I think I have the 20. something version of the OS. I've only downloaded it and installed it a about a week ago, end of 9/21 and and I've had it on most all the time since.